# Unknown phantom user "wordpress" created with admin privileges

Tags: admin, security, wp-cli

We've been seeing a user created out of nowhere named "wordpress" every so often, with most of our wordpress sites on a couple Ubuntu 20 servers. I run a quick audit across our server using WP-CLI to find all administrator users every once in a while, to be sure we aren't providing extra admin access to user accounts.

We then see most of our sites have a user:
"wordpress"
with ID "123456"
no email address associated with it
and registered on 9-28-2012 00:00:00

I have tried to search google/stack to see if anyone has reported the same thing happening to them, but its difficult to search for because of the keywords being used. And I don't see anything remotely mentioning this thing happening to anyone else.

Has anyone seen this, or know how its happening? I am worried its a security vulnerability that I am not aware of, or a plugin needing updating. We're not fully up to date on all wordpress and plugin updates on all sites, but many/most of them are, or at least fairly recently. We've seen this happen before on a couple sites back in 2020 so it can't be a wordpress or plugin issue for that long since we've definitely updated since then.

One thing to note is we do a lot of our updates from WP-CLI, but have also done it from admin panel using an Ubuntu user named "wordpress".... but I don't see how that would ever create a new user in our wordpress user table.

[image: Wp CLI Admin User list]

Comment: I haven’t heard of hacks creating users before. Do you have any record of this user logging in? I can’t remember if there’s a last login time in the user record or meta. Does anyone else have shell access to the server? Ditto I can’t remember if it’s possible to create a fixed user ID through WordPress APIs but I’d guess not, so sounds like they’re running SQL to do this.

Comment: I don't see a way after the fact to get user login details. I thought it was in user meta data but I don't see anything for any user there. I know there's plugins you can install for that, but I've since deleted all worpress users. I've tested using WP CLI without an email but that's a required field. The user ID being 123456 and the date registered is too specific as that is not a default for mysql inserts. But at the same time, not sure how a user can be created in the DB without required fields if not direct to mysql. Both backend admin and WP CLI won't let you. It's very odd.

Comment: Also my auto-increment value on all these user tables are "123457" now, as that was also set based on the last insert value.